# Guake flashes white when closing

Tags: graphics, compiz, guake

When I close Guake, using <kbd>F12</kbd>, instead of fading out as it does on my laptop, it just flashes white.

The activation animation works fine, it flies in from full transparency and quickly fades in.

Ubuntu version: 14.10

What's the problem here and how should I fix it? It's extremely distracting and annoying on darker backgrounds.

Comment: Any composition managers running? Compiz or Compton, ect?

Comment: @anon Yes, Compiz is running.